# (NLP) Natural Language Processing Dependancy Libraries issue

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am trying to create a NLP demo and when i am creating dependency parsing i am getting this error.

My Code:

```
from nltk.grammar import DependencyGrammar
from nltk.parse import (DependencyGraph,ProjectiveDependencyParser, NonprojectiveDependencyParser)
    dg = DependencyGraph(text)
    dg.tree().pprint()
    for head,dep,rel in     dg.triples():
        print('({h[0]}, {h[1]}), {r}, ({d[0]}, {d[1]})'.format(h=head, r=rel, d=dep))
```

And Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/indianic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.py", line 351, in _parse
    cell_extractor = extractors[cell_number]
KeyError: 111

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 77, in <module>
    dependency(text)
  File "demo.py", line 69, in dependency
    dg = DependencyGraph(text)
  File "/home/indianic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.py", line 90, in __init__
    top_relation_label=top_relation_label,
  File "/home/indianic/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.py", line 355, in _parse
    'CoNLL(10) or Malt-Tab(4) format'.format(cell_number)
ValueError: Number of tab-delimited fields (111) not supported by CoNLL(10) or Malt-Tab(4) format.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Which part of the error message do you think is unclear?

Comment: Could you provide an example for `text` where this error shows up? So that we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** you need to be careful with your input `text`.

Providing plain text will indeed fail:

```
>> DependencyGraph("random sentence")
 ...
 ValueError: Number of tab-delimited fields (2) not supported by CoNLL(10) or Malt-Tab(4) format
```

As you may see from its documentation, [DependencyGraph](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/dependencygraph.html) is taking as input a string with [Malt-TAB format](https://cl.lingfil.uu.se/~nivre/research/MaltXML.html) or [CoNLL format](https://universaldependencies.org/format.html).

Some examples are shown [here](http://www.nltk.org/howto/dependency.html). Find one below:

```
>>> treebank_data = """Pierre  NNP     2       NMOD
... Vinken  NNP     8       SUB
... ,       ,       2       P
... 61      CD      5       NMOD
... years   NNS     6       AMOD
... old     JJ      2       NMOD
... ,       ,       2       P
... will    MD      0       ROOT
... join    VB      8       VC
... the     DT      11      NMOD
... board   NN      9       OBJ
... as      IN      9       VMOD
... a       DT      15      NMOD
... nonexecutive    JJ      15      NMOD
... director        NN      12      PMOD
... Nov.    NNP     9       VMOD
... 29      CD      16      NMOD
... .       .       9       VMOD
... """
>>> dg = DependencyGraph(treebank_data)
```

So your input `text` should contain tab separated values such as CoNLL or Malt-Tab format, as is requested from the error message you get.